# rake aborted: LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/deploy/myapp/config/application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am getting following error while running command

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
```

I am using rvm and ruby version is 2.3.1.

Here is output

```
deploy@localhost:~/my-sources$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
--trace rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- /home/deploy/myapp/config/application
/home/deploy/myapp-sources/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/deploy/myapp-sources/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in  `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@global/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in
`load' /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:74:in `kernel_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli/exec.rb:28:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:463:in `exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:27:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/cli.rb:18:in `start'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:124:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.17.1/exe/bundle:22:in `<top (required)>' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load' /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
`<main>'
```

Comment: Please edit your question to use a code block instead of a blockquote.

Comment: Why the directory you're supposedly running this from say `my-sources`, then the first line of the stack trace says `/home/deploy/myapp`, and then lines 2-3 say `/home/deploy/myapp-sources`? Were you running a command from the wrong folder? Are you referencing one application from inside the other? Can you clarify what is on line 4 of the `Rakefile`, where you are running this from, and which folders exist?